# Looking for an incomplete metric space $X$ , all whose singletons are open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Does there exist an incomplete metric space whose metric topology is discrete ( not the discrete metric ) ? Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Hinnt: Can you think of one with the metric inherited from the ordinary metric on the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the subset $X = \{\frac{1}{n} \mid n\in\mathbb{Z_+}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I know it's incomplete ; why is every singleton open ?

Comment: Take any $\frac{1}{n}$. Then it is open in $X$ since you can find a ball around it (say the ball of radius $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$) that does not intersect any other $\frac{1}{m}$.